# Solving for complex eigen vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was reading about complex eigen vectors from [here](http://www.sosmath.com/matrix/eigen3/eigen3.html).

The given matrix is 
$$A=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        3 & -2\\
        4 & -1\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

The roots are found as $1\pm2i$.
The article then uses the eigen value $1+2i$ and rewrites the system as

$$(2-2i)x-2y=0 $$
$$4x-(2+2i)y=0$$

Then it goes on saying:

> In fact the two equations are identical since $(2+2i)(2-2i)=8$.So the system reduces to one equation $(1-i)x-y=0$

I didnt get this.

Comment: The system of linear equations stems from inputting the value of the eigenvalue in the equation $\;\det (tI-A)\;$ , which makes the matrix $\;\lambda I-A\;$ *singular*. Thus, that homogeneous system has a non-trivial solution and thus one of the equations **must** be a linear combination of the other one(s) ...

Comment: For any $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$, if it is singular, then you must be able to write one column (row) in terms of the other.

Comment: Ok I got this: $2[(1-i)x-y]=(2-2i)x-2y$ and $[(1-i)x-y](2+2i) = 4x-(2+2i)y$, but still didnt get from where $(2+2i)(2-2i)=8$ has come. Must be doing something really stupid here.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

from the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
(2-2i)x-2y=0\\
4x-(2+2i)y=0
\end{cases}
$$
multipling the first equation by $4$ and the second by $(2-2i)$, you have:

$$
\begin{cases}
4(2-2i)x-8y=0\\
4(2-2i)x-(2+2i)(2-2i)y=0
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
4(2-2i)x-8y=0\\
4(2-2i)x-8y=0
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think that the remark about $(2+2i)(2-2i)=8$ is completely useless.

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $A$, then, by definition, $A-\lambda I$ has rank $<n$ (where $n$ is the order of the matrix $A$).

Thus the matrix of the system you're looking at has rank $<2$. Since the rank is at least $1$, you conclude that one of the equations is redundant, *without* any need to check. Just choose a non trivial one, in this case either of the two.

In case $n>3$ one can't predict which of the equations will be redundant, because the only information is that the rank is less than $n$, but it could be anything from $0$ to $n-1$, depending on the matrix and the eigenvalue.

Comment: OK if that is useless then how the reduction to $(1-i)x-y$ is done?

Comment: @Mahesha999 Just take the first equation and remove the common factor $2$.

Comment: hey damn thanks...just want to know if there is any fact behind: *If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $A$, then, by definition, $A-\lambda I$ has rank $<n$ (where $n$ is the order of the matrix $A$).* I am missing something simple intuitive stuff?

Comment: @Mahesha999 There is $v\ne0$ with $Av=\lambda v$, which is the same as saying that $v\ne0$ is in the null space of $A-\lambda I$; having non zero null space and rank $<n$ are equivalent conditions for an $n\times n$ matrix. Thus one can think to the definition of eigenvalue as “$A-\lambda I$ is not invertible”.